# Creating a toggle/switch to show different information

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vue.js

I'm quite new to this but I'm trying to recreate a toggle that will show monthly/annual payments whether a monthly or annual button is clicked, similar to this: https://search4less.com/#pricing.

I have 2 sets of price cards in place  but I'm not sure how to connect the toggles so it will work as expected. I'm using vue with this project.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is the code im using

```
    <div class="container">
  <label for="toggle_button">
        <span v-if="isActive" class="toggle__label">Monthly</span>
        <span v-if="! isActive" class="toggle__label">Annually</span>

        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_button" v-model="checkedValue">
        <span class="toggle__switch"></span>
    </label>

    <b-row class="monthly">
   <b-col>       
    <b-card class="price-card">
        <template #header>
        <h4 class="mb-0 content-center title-colour">Search4Less</h4>
        </template>

        <b-card-body>
        <b-card-sub-title class="mb-2 content-center">€20<small style="font-size:10px">/per user</small></b-card-sub-title>

        <hr class="my-4">

        <b-card-text class="content-center">
            Limitless access Irish business<br>
             Intelligence Information.
        </b-card-text>

        <b-card-text class="small-text"><small style="font-size:14px;">(includes)</small></b-card-text>

        </b-card-body>

        <b-list-group class="content-center" flush>
        <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Company Reports</b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Director Reports</b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Business Reports</b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>CRO Filings</b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Watchlist</b-list-group-item>
        </b-list-group>

        <hr class="my-4">

        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <b-button variant="success">Subscribe Now</b-button>
        </div>

        
    </b-card>
    </b-col>   
    <b-col>
        <b-card class="price-card">
            <template #header>
            <h4 class="mb-0 content-center title-colour">Search4Less Plus</h4>
            </template>

            <b-card-body>
            <b-card-sub-title class="mb-2 content-center">€25<small style="font-size:10px">/per user</small></b-card-sub-title>

            <hr class="my-4">

            <b-card-text class="content-center">
                All of the Search4less features +<br> 
                any 1 of the following
            </b-card-text>

            <b-card-text class="small-text"><small style="font-size:14px;">(any one)</small></b-card-text>

            </b-card-body>

            <b-list-group flush class="content-center">
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>UK Data Access</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Export Bundle</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Due Dil Reports</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Document Search</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Enhanced Watchlist</b-list-group-item>
            </b-list-group>

            <hr class="my-4">

            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <b-button variant="success">Subscribe Now</b-button>
            </div>

            
        </b-card>
    </b-col>
    <b-col>
        <b-card class="price-card">
            <template #header>
            <h4 class="mb-0 content-center title-colour">Search4Less Pro</h4>
            </template>

            <b-card-body>
            <b-card-sub-title class="mb-2 content-center price-colour">€30<small style="font-size:10px">/per user</small></b-card-sub-title>

            <hr class="my-4">

            <b-card-text class="content-center">
                All of the Search4less and<br> 
                Search4less plus features.
            </b-card-text>

            <b-card-text class="small-text"><small style="font-size:14px;">(best value)</small></b-card-text>

            </b-card-body>

            <b-list-group class="content-center" flush>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>More Data sets</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>All Features</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Saves time</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Relevant Results</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Better Insights</b-list-group-item>
            </b-list-group>

            <hr class="my-4">

            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <b-button variant="success">Subscribe Now</b-button>
            </div>    

            
        </b-card>
        
    </b-col>    
 </b-row> 
</div>
<b-row class="annually" hidden>
   <b-col>     
    <b-card class="price-card">
        <template #header>
        <h4 class="mb-0 content-center title-colour">Search4Less</h4>
        </template>

        <b-card-body>
        <b-card-sub-title class="mb-2 content-center">€195<small style="font-size:10px">/per user p/a</small></b-card-sub-title>

        <hr class="my-4">

        <b-card-text class="content-center">
            Limitless access Irish business<br>
             Intelligence Information.
        </b-card-text>

        <b-card-text class="small-text"><small style="font-size:14px;">(includes)</small></b-card-text>

        </b-card-body>

        <b-list-group class="content-center" flush>
        <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Company Reports</b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Director Reports</b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Business Reports</b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>CRO Filings</b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Watchlist</b-list-group-item>
        </b-list-group>

        <hr class="my-4">

        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <b-button variant="success">Start Trial Now</b-button>
            <b-button variant="success">Subscribe Now</b-button>
        </div>

        
    </b-card>
    </b-col>   
    <b-col>
        <b-card class="price-card">
            <template #header>
            <h4 class="mb-0 content-center title-colour">Search4Less Plus</h4>
            </template>

            <b-card-body>
            <b-card-sub-title class="mb-2 content-center">€245<small style="font-size:10px">/per user p/a</small></b-card-sub-title>

            <hr class="my-4">

            <b-card-text class="content-center">
                All of the Search4less features +<br> 
                any 1 of the following
            </b-card-text>

            <b-card-text class="small-text"><small style="font-size:14px;">(any one)</small></b-card-text>

            </b-card-body>

            <b-list-group flush class="content-center">
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>UK Data Access</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Export Bundle</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Due Dil Reports</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Document Search</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Enhanced Watchlist</b-list-group-item>
            </b-list-group>

            <hr class="my-4">

            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <b-button variant="success">Start Trial Now</b-button>
                <b-button variant="success">Subscribe Now</b-button>
            </div>

            
        </b-card>
    </b-col>
    <b-col>
        <b-card class="price-card">
            <template #header>
            <h4 class="mb-0 content-center title-colour">Search4Less Pro</h4>
            </template>

            <b-card-body>
            <b-card-sub-title class="mb-2 content-center price-colour">€295<small style="font-size:10px">/per user p/a</small></b-card-sub-title>

            <hr class="my-4">

            <b-card-text class="content-center">
                All of the Search4less and<br> 
                Search4less plus features.
            </b-card-text>

            <b-card-text class="small-text"><small style="font-size:14px;">(best value)</small></b-card-text>

            </b-card-body>

            <b-list-group class="content-center" flush>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>More Data sets</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>All Features</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Saves time</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Relevant Results</b-list-group-item>
            <b-list-group-item><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green;"></i>Better Insights</b-list-group-item>
            </b-list-group>

            <hr class="my-4">

            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <b-button variant="success">Start Trial Now</b-button>
                <b-button variant="success">Subscribe Now</b-button>
            </div>    

            
        </b-card>
    </b-col>    
 </b-row>

</body>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Pricing',
    
    data() {
        return {
            currentState: false
        }
    },

    computed: {
        isActive() {
            return this.currentState;
        },

        checkedValue: {
            get() {
                return this.defaultState
            },
            set(newValue) {
                this.currentState = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need JavaScript:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
}

.cards > div {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

#toggle + label:before {
  content: 'Monthly';
}

#toggle:checked + label:before {
  content: 'Yearly';
}

#toggle:not(:checked) ~ .cards > :last-child {
  display: none;
}

#toggle:checked ~ .cards > :first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<label for="toggle"></label>
<div class="cards">
  <div>
    <h3>Monthly</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Yearly</h3>
    <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another example:

```css
input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + div {
    display: none;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "tabHeaderA tabHeaderB"
        "tabContentA tabContentA";
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

label[for="a"] {
    grid-area: tabHeaderA;
}

label[for="b"] {
    grid-area: tabHeaderB;
}

#a + div {
    grid-area: tabContentA;
}

#b + div {
    grid-area: tabContentA;
}

label:hover {
  background-color: silver;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    border-block-start: 1px solid black;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

label:first-child {
    border-inline-start: 1px solid black;
}

label:not(:last-child) {
    border-inline-end: 1px solid black;
}

div {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<label for="a">A</label>
<input type="radio" name="tab" id="a" checked>
<div>Content for A</div>
<label for="b">B</label>
<input type="radio" name="tab" id="b">
<div>Content for B</label>
```

Comment: Wow I did not imagine you could do this with just CSS. Nice work!!

Comment: Could you possibly suggest a way to adjust the UI to be more of a simple "toggle" concept based on your current markup? This UI is a stretch for me to grasp/apply.

Comment: I added another example to the answer. Is that better?

Comment: Hi, yes using a radio button will probably help me find some styling options out there—thank you!! 

Comment: Sorry @shaedrich - This couldn't work for my situation due to the nature of the markup (also, the check/radio choice makes no difference... in fact checkbox might be less confusing haha). I created a new question here if you want to see if you can speak to it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77783768/creating-a-toggle-switch-to-show-hide-divs-css-only Thanks again. =)