# Creating a toggle/switch to show/hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to be able to click the toggle UI element (checkbox), and have it show/hide one or the other div.

The current CSS (below) is just some styling; and I can't change my basic DIV HTML structure.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer; }
  input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
    outline: 0; }

.toggle {
  height: 32px;
  width: 52px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid #474755;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #2D2F39 0%, #1F2027 100%);
  transition: all .2s ease; }
  .toggle:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.2);
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.1, 0.75, 1.35); }
  .toggle:checked {
    border-color: #654FEC; }
    .toggle:checked:after {
      transform: translatex(20px); }
```

```html
<div id="a">...</div>
<div id="b">...</div>
<div id="c">
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" checked>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="d">...</div>
<div id="content-one">Content one</div>
<div id="content-two">Content two</div>
<div id="e">...</div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I also wanted to share a simpler version that ChatGPT (Bing Chat) provided (did nothing, LOL):

```css
  #content-two {
    display: none;
  }
  .toggle:checked ~ #content-two {
    display: normal;
  }
  .toggle:checked ~ #content-one {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="a">...</div>
<div id="b">...</div>
<div id="c">
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" checked>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="d">...</div>
<div id="content-one">Content one</div>
<div id="content-two">Content two</div>
<div id="e">...</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `:has()` and `:not(:has())` will do the trick

*Note: `:has()` only available in latest Firefox (version 121), before that it was available behind a config switch, but was kind of broken under some conditions)*

*Also, not widely available in mobile browsers, outside of the main ones (chrome/safari are good)*

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.toggle {
  height: 32px;
  width: 52px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid #474755;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #2D2F39 0%, #1F2027 100%);
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.toggle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.1, 0.75, 1.35);
}

.toggle:checked {
  border-color: #654FEC;
}

.toggle:checked:after {
  transform: translatex(20px);
}

#c:has(.toggle:checked) ~ [id=content-one] {
  display: none;
}
#c:not(:has(.toggle:checked)) ~ [id=content-two] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">...</div>
<div id="b">...</div>
<div id="c">
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" checked>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="d">...</div>
<div id="content-one">Content one</div>
<div id="content-two">Content two</div>
<div id="e">...</div>
```

Comment: clean and elegant solution

Comment: Thanks, amazing! I figured out something similar based on your original comment . This works in CodePen and here; but for some reason my WordPress page builder the CSS window is showing errors, saying `"Expected RPAREN at col 8"` for the line with `#c:has(.toggle:checked)`, and the same for col 13 for the line with `#c:not(:has(.toggle:checked))`; and it doesn't work (I will check with their support to see what is up)!

Comment: @Drewdavid it's saying `"` ... an odd thing to say - it may be that `:has` is considered invalid by whatever your *page builder* is - perhaps it needs an update

Comment: Fixed my above comment to be more specific. Yeah guessing that is the case. Boo. Thank you again! Maybe they will update it when they see this issue. I will mark your answer as correct in any case. =)